# les sardines -- is it plural or singular?

Tags: grammaire

I'm reading *Le Poisson-scie et sa cousine* by Pierre Béarn and got confused on what the first stanza (literally) means.

I suppose " Un poisson-scie s'encolérait d'avoir perdu chez les sardines, une cousine qu'il aimait " is saying the sawfish lost his way in the home of his cousin, some sardines, then the sawfish got angry. But the sardines appear both as plural (*les sardines*) and singular (*une cousine*) here, isn't that conflicting? Or, is it that there's no singular form for sardines in French?

The full content of the poem is as below

> Le Poisson-scie et sa cousine
>
> Pierre Béarn
>
> Un poisson-scie s'encolérait
> d'avoir perdu chez les sardines
> une cousine qu'il aimait .
>
> -- Rendez-la-moi sales gamines ,
> leur criait-il d'un air mauvais ,
> ou je vous change en orphelines !
>
> -- Foutriquet ! dit une bambine ,
> ne vois-tu pas que ta cousine
> est avec nous dans un filet ?
>
> L'énervé dut scier les rets
> d'où s'échappèrent les sardines
> mais lui resta dans le filet :
>
> Il s'était trompé de cousine .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Les sardines* is a plural. The sawfish didn't lose his way, he lost his *cousin*. Your confusion comes from giving the verb an unaccusative interpretation. *Avoir perdu* is the past infinitive of the transitive verb *perdre (quelque chose)* 'to lose (something)'; by contrast, "getting lost", in French, would be conveyed as *se perdre*, and, in the perfect, *s'être perdu* (i.e. you would have a reflexive pronoun, and therefore, the auxiliary *être*).

```
A sawfish was getting angry
For having lost, at the sardines' home,
A female cousin that he loved.

-- Give her back to me, you naughty kids,
He was yelling with a nasty face,
Or I will turn you into orphans!

-- You little prick! one child said,
Can you not see that your cousin
Is here with us inside a net?

The angry one had to saw the net,
From which the sardines could escape;
But as for him, he stayed within the net:

He had spotted the wrong cousin.
```

Comment: I see, reflective or non-reflective, could be totally different meaning....

Comment: compare with English: to have lost something, to be lost.

Comment: @athos reflexive

Comment: @njzk2 But *to be lost* is stative; in French it does not involve the reflexive pronoun. The right comparison is with *to **get** lost*:
*être perdu* 'to be lost' vs. *se perdre* 'to get lost' (and in the past form *avoir été perdu* 'have been lost' vs. *s'être perdu* 'have got lost').